# Unable to loop through selection of multiple elements from a grid

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I'm trying to select multiple rows from a grid by control clicking on each row but only the first one seems to be clicked.

This is what I'm trying:

```
this.selectScan = async function (rows) {
    for (let i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        let scanRow = scansList.element(by.css("div[row=\"" + rows[i] + "\"]")).element(by.css("div[colid=\"originalFilename\"]"));
        await browser.actions()
            .mouseMove(scanRow)
            .keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
            .click()
            .keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
            .perform();
    }
};
```

I'm calling this by passing an array of row ids as:

```
selectScan(["2", "3"]);
```

I've also tried to chain all the key and mouse clicks and then execute perform() as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484736/protractor-ctrl-click) but it didn't help.

Comment: why you choose to use `mouseover()`, did `scanRow.click()` not work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by simulating CTLR keyDown, then clicking on element and then releasing the CTRL key:

```
 this.selectScan = async function (rows) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        let scanRow = scansList.element(by.css("div[row=\"" + rows[i] + "\"]")).element(by.css("div[colid=\"originalFilename\"]"));
        await browser.actions()
            .keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
            .perform();
        await scanRow.click();
        await browser.actions()
            .keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
            .perform();
    }
};
```